# Laravel nesting models. Sub entity on user model?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I am having trouble figuring out how to attach sub entities to the user model.

Lets say I have two tables: Users and Nationality. The relationship is many to one (users:nationality), meaning every user has exactly 1 nationality. Lets say the users table has row called "nationality" which simply maps a user to their nationality in the nationality table.

Lets say i pass vanilla user model to a view
`$aUser = User::find(1);`

`{{$aUser->nationality}}` will show `2`

Rather than showing the id, i want the user object to include the nationality object. For example, i want `{{$aUser->nationality}}` to output `Australia` rather than the id associated with Australia.

Answer (score 2):

Use **`with`** method

```
$user= User::with('nationality')->find($id);
```

Print $user and see the data you get. (Instead of `$id` use 1 as user id in your case)

Note: There must be Relation in **User.php** as

```
public function nationality(){
//.........
//hasOne, belongsTo etc based on your relation
}
```

Comment: This code is not correct in case of selecting user by id that is exclusively unique: `$user= User::where(array('id'=>$id))->with('nationality')->get();` - will return array with one object. so change `->get()` to `->first()` to make it return an object (not object in array).  second moment is that ORM has shorthand: `find($id)`, so don't afraid to use it: `User::with('nationality')->find($id)`

Answer (score 2):

Let's say You've model Nationality:

```
class Nationality extends Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model 
{
    // other stuff

    // relation between Nationality (id) <-> User (nationality_id)  
    public function users()
    {
      return $this->hasMany(User::class);
    }

    // some other stuff
}
```

keep in mind to satisfy this conventions:

1)  Your `nationalities` table must have `id`, `name` fields

2) Your `users` table must have `nationality_id` field

And Your User model will be like:

```
class User extends Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model 
{
  // other stuff

  // relation between User (nationality_id) <-> Nationality (id)  
  public function nationality()
  {
    return $this->belongsTo(Nationality::class);
  }

  // some other stuff
}
```

Now let's ask ORM to give data with related things:

```
$User = User::with(['nationality'])->find(1);
```

in views:

```
{{ ($User->nationality)? $User->nationality->name : '' }}
```

bonus:

```
// we made Nationality model to return us all users that has nationality: Australia
$Nationality = Nationality::with(['users'])
                            ->where(['name' => 'Australia'])
                            ->first();
$users = $Nationality->users;

// or
$Nationality = Nationality::with(['users'])->find($nationalityId);
$users = $Nationality->users;

// and of course eager loading is not good when Your users table is huge, 
// so better do it simply like this:
$users = User::where('nationality_id', '=', $nationalityId)->paginate(20);
```